# Swift Functions and parameters

Tags: swift, function

I'm a total noob and have been given the below problem to solve but don't know where to start as simple as it may be.

I'm looking to write a function that accepts a string as a parameter and returns true or false.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

Comment: **func first(_ str:String)->Bool {  ..... return true/false}**

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is:

```
func foo(variable: String) -> Bool{
    //do stuff
    return true //or false
}

//You call the function by this:
var boolVariable = foo("Hello World")
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: You would need to call foo using foo(variable: “Hello World”) or add an external _ parameter to the function declaration. For instance, func foo( _ variable: String) -> Bool {}